# Freemarker iterating over hashmap in list of map

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I have seen the similar questions, but still could not found greatly solution.

This program:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
String abc = "a,b,c";

for(String x : abc.split(",")){
  // how to get this ?
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("one", x);
  map.put("two", x);
  map.put("three",x);
  list.add(map);
}

HashMap<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
root.put("abc",list);
root.put("test", "value");
```

If I want use freemark program to iterate map from root map, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your code into the model bean in a method

```
  public HashMap<String, Object> getRoot() {
    // ... your code
    return root;
  }
```

then you can access the list of maps under the `abc` key like this:

```
[
<#list root['abc'] as map>
  {
  <#list map?keys as key>
    ${key}: ${map[key]}
  </#list>
  }
</#list>
]
```

Instead of `root['abc']`, you could also use `root.abc`, but the first version stresses that `abc` is a hash map key, not a property of `root`.

This is the resulting output:

```
[
  {
    two: a
    one: a
    three: a
  }
  {
    two: b
    one: b
    three: b
  }
  {
    two: c
    one: c
    three: c
  }
]
```